# Docker. How to run my container on a specific local ip

Tags: macos, docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I have such a simple `docker-compose.yml` file, that is serving some static files:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: docs_nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Now it can be accessed at

- `127.0.0.1`
- `0.0.0.0`

Is it possible somehow to tweak the `docker-compose.yml` to run my container at `127.127.127.127`, for example?

As an answer I'll accept a working `docker-compose.yml` example, cause I've read a lot about networking in docs/blogs, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a network along with the services you wish to run. Then you give a static ip address within the range of the base IP and CIDR mask. Since I don't know your network, you will need to match this closer to your network configuration so gateway can connect to the internet through the same gateway as your host machine. There should be away to set it up so the gateway will route through the host, but I don't remember off the top of my hand how to manage that. I'm sure there is a more specific how-to that will describe that process. I will look when I have a chance to find the answer, to that question.

`version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: docs_nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
          vpcbr:
            ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
          volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#custom-network-plugins

this gives a pretty good idea of what's going on when creating a network for docker containers. When you call docker-compose it's translating the network key into network commands.

Note: I can not guarantee this will work since I don't know your setup. But this should get you in the ball park.

let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pick an IP address that your host can route to. If your host IP address is say 192.168.0.50 it could look something like this in the yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:   host1:
networks:
  mynet:
    ipv4_address: 192.168.0.101 networks:   mynet:
driver: bridge
ipam:
  config:
  - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
```

You could also specify the IP address in a startup script using the manual steps listed at: 
https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/

Comment: Thanks, but it says `ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 41`

Comment: Please post the whole yml file.

Comment: I've already posted the whole file. It's in the description of the problem. It's very simple and small. I've only added your lines to the bottom. Could you write a "properly merged" yml file?

Comment: My problem is that I am using docker for mac, and you cannot reach the containers from the mac host: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/ "Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers." and "The docker (Linux) bridge network is not reachable from the macOS host."